# What is the equivalent part for Linux docker Runc on the Windows docker?

Tags: docker, runc

Forgive me I just began to learn to understand `Docker`. As I knew , `Docker` used to depend on the `LXC`. then go to the `libcontainer` .Now it is `Runc`(from docker 1.11). which is the implement of `OCF`(Open Container Format). And also I knew `Runc` can only run on the Linux. So `Runc` is the underneath of the Linux docker. My question is What is the equivalent for Linux docker `Runc` on the Windows docker? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Docker on Windows uses the Host Compute Service, via https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim. The HCS provides an inteface for starting containers on Windows. Microsoft went with this way instead of providing low level APIs because the low level API was evolving, but Docker needed a stable API to build upon.

See this technet article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/01/27/introducing-the-host-compute-service-hcs/ for more information.